# ClientX & ClientY not updating fast enough when they are triggered via the mousemove event. Why?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mousemove

I have the following code with the expectation that the trails of divs following mouse will change position depending on the direction the mouse is moving. It seems that the divs' orientation only updates when I move my mouse very quickly.

When I move my mouse slowly, the event still fires, but the position of the trailing divs do not change accordingly. Why is this the case? Is this an issue with my code or with how quickly the mousemove event updates the ClientX & ClientY properties? Thanks!

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');

let previousLeft = 0;
let previousTop = 0;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let leftMouse = e.clientX;
  let topMouse = e.clientY;
const mouseTrails = document.querySelectorAll('.mouseTrail');

  const setTrail = ((offsetX, offsetY) => {
    for (i = 0; i < mouseTrails.length; i++) {
      mouseTrails[i].style.left = leftMouse + "px";
      mouseTrails[i].style.top = topMouse + "px";
      mouseTrails[i].style.display = "block";

      leftMouse += offsetX;
      topMouse += offsetY;
    }
  });

  if (leftMouse > previousLeft && topMouse > previousTop) {
    setTrail(-20, -20);
  } else if (leftMouse < previousLeft && topMouse < previousTop) {
    setTrail(20, 20);
  } else if (leftMouse > previousLeft && topMouse < previousTop) {
    setTrail(-20, 20);
  } else if (leftMouse < previousLeft && topMouse > previousTop) {
    setTrail(20, -20);
  } else {
    setTrail(0, 0);
  }

  previousLeft = leftMouse;
  previousTop = topMouse;
});
```

```css
.mouseTrail {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mouseTrail"></div>
<div class="mouseTrail"></div>
<div class="mouseTrail"></div>
<div class="mouseTrail"></div>
<div class="mouseTrail"></div>
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is move `const mouseTrails = document.querySelectorAll('.mouseTrail');` outside of the listener, and see if that makes an improvement. Every time you move the mouse you're picking up the elements again and again, and you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: I've put your code in a snippet that you can run. It would suggest that something else is going on because it seems to work fine (with which Jordan agrees judging from their answer).

Answer (score 0):

It could be to do with the speed of the browser you are using. For me personally the code appears to work as expected.

There are a few optimisations you can make to your code that could potentially speed it up.

Firstly, you are querying the DOM and creating a new 'setTrail' function every time the mousemove event is fired.  You can move these outside your listener so that the only code that is executed when the mouse moves is the code to move your trails.

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');

let previousLeft = 0;
let previousTop = 0;

const mouseTrails = document.querySelectorAll('.mouseTrail');

function setTrail(x, y, offsetX, offsetY) {
    for (i = 0; i < mouseTrails.length; i++){
        mouseTrails[i].style.left = x + "px";
        mouseTrails[i].style.top = y + "px";
        mouseTrails[i].style.display = "block";
        x += offsetX;
        y += offsetY;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    let leftMouse = e.clientX;
    let topMouse = e.clientY;

    if(leftMouse > previousLeft && topMouse > previousTop){
         setTrail(leftMouse, topMouse, -20, -20);
    }
    else if(leftMouse < previousLeft && topMouse < previousTop){
         setTrail(leftMouse, topMouse, 20, 20);
    }
    else if(leftMouse > previousLeft && topMouse < previousTop){
         setTrail(leftMouse, topMouse, -20, 20);
    }
    else if(leftMouse < previousLeft && topMouse > previousTop){
         setTrail(leftMouse, topMouse, 20, -20);
    }        
    else{
         setTrail(leftMouse, topMouse, 0,0);
    }
    previousLeft = leftMouse;
    previousTop = topMouse;
});
```